# flutter web: how to obfuscate/minify the js code (in addition to the dart code)

Tags: javascript, flutter, minify

I have a flutter web app which has some code in dart and some other code in javascript. When I build the release variant of the web app, the dart code seems to be obfuscated/minified. But the javascript code is not. The javascript code can be seen in the build/web/src directory as plain human readable source code.

How can I obfuscate/minify the js code? Is it possible with the flutter build command? or do I have to use some other tooling after the flutter build step?

Comment: Obfuscation and minification are two very different things but since this is JS there's a package/packages to do both of those things. In terms of whether this is possible to chain into the build command I'm not sure. You could just add extra steps in the build process to run the obfuscation (if you need it) in one step, then the minification, then the flutter build command. I'd retain two separate dirs for the JS, one for minified and or obfuscated code and one for the unmodified source code.

Comment: thank you @LewisFarnworth for your suggestion. Is it better to do the obfuscation/minification of JS before the flutter build or after the flutter build?

Comment: I'm not au fait on the workings of flutter's build command but my gut feeling is to do the JS build step(s) first.  Since both are interpreted languages it's likely possible to do it either way around, though I'm not sure exactly how flutter bundles the JS so to me it makes more sense to make the changes to your JS before it gets bundled in the host runtime (Dart).